# Returning multidimensional array from function

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

How do I return a multidimensional array stored in a `private` field of my class?

```
class Myclass {
private:
   int myarray[5][5];
public:
   int **get_array();
};

// This does not work:
int **Myclass::get_array() {
    return myarray;
}
```

I get the following error:

> cannot convert `int (*)[5][5]` to `int**` in return

Comment: what is grid ? shouldn't it be `myarray`?

Comment: Returning a direct reference to a private member may not always be a good idea - you effectively break encapsulation by this, allowing anyone to access and modify your private member. This may or may not be acceptable in your design.

Comment: @MIkhail: Since justin hasn't been online since the minute he posted this question, I took the liberty to fix it.

Comment: You can use [Matrix library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50886558/7580839).

Answer (score 28):

A two-dimensional array does not decay to a pointer to pointer to ints. It decays to a pointer to arrays of ints - that is, only the first dimension decays to a pointer. The pointer does not point to int pointers, which when incremented advance by the size of a pointer, but to arrays of 5 integers.

```
class Myclass {
private:
    int myarray[5][5];
public:
    typedef int (*pointer_to_arrays)[5]; //typedefs can make things more readable with such awkward types

    pointer_to_arrays get_array() {return myarray;}
};

int main()
{
    Myclass o;
    int (*a)[5] = o.get_array();
    //or
    Myclass::pointer_to_arrays b = o.get_array();
}
```

A pointer to pointer (`int**`) is used when each subarray is allocated separately (that is, you originally have an array of pointers)

```
int* p[5];
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    p[i] = new int[5];
}
```

Here we have an array of five pointers, each pointing to the first item in a separate memory block, altogether 6 distinct memory blocks.

In a two-dimensional array you get a single contiguous block of memory:

```
int arr[5][5]; //a single block of 5 * 5 * sizeof(int) bytes
```

You should see that the memory layout of these things are completely different, and therefore these things cannot be returned and passed the same way.

Answer (score 18):

There are two possible types that you can return to provide access to your internal array. The old C style would be returning `int *[5]`, as the array will easily decay into a pointer to the first element, which is of type `int[5]`.

```
int (*foo())[5] {
   static int array[5][5] = {};
   return array;
}
```

Now, you can also return a proper reference to the internal array, the simplest syntax would be through a typedef:

```
typedef int (&array5x5)[5][5];
array5x5 foo() {
   static int array[5][5] = {};
   return array;
}
```

Or a little more cumbersome without the typedef:

```
int (&foo())[5][5] {
   static int array[5][5] = {};
   return array;
}
```

The advantage of the C++ version is that the actual type is maintained, and that means that the actual size of the array is known at the callers side.

Comment: Though be careful how you use those typedefs, sometimes: `delete[] new array5x5()` (looks like new, but it's really new[]).

Answer (score 8):

To return a pointer to your array of array member, the type needed is `int (*)[5]`, not `int **`:

```
class Myclass {
private:
    int myarray[5][5];
public:
    int (*get_array())[5];
};

int (*Myclass::get_array())[5] {
    return myarray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I return a multidimensional array hidden in a private field?

If it's supposed to be hidden, why are you returning it in the first place?

Anyway, you cannot return arrays from functions, but you can return a pointer to the first element. What is the first element of a 5x5 array of ints? An array of 5 ints, of course:

```
int (*get_grid())[5]
{
    return grid;
}
```

Alternatively, you could return the entire array by reference:

```
int (&get_grid())[5][5]
{
    return grid;
}
```

...welcome to C declarator syntax hell ;-)

May I suggest `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` or `boost::multi_array<int, 2>` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Simpler would be `decltype(auto)` (since C++14)

```
decltype(auto) get_array() { return (myarray); } // Extra parents to return reference
```

then `decltype` (since C++11) (member should be declared before the method though)

```
auto get_array() -> decltype((this->myarray)) { return myarray; }
// or
auto get_array() -> decltype(this->myarray)& { return myarray; }
```

then typedef way:

```
using int2D = int[5][5]; // since C++11
// or
typedef int int2D[5][5];

int2D& get_array() { return myarray; }
```

as regular syntax is very ugly way:

```
int (&get_array())[5][5] { return myarray; }
```

Using `std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5>` (since C++11) would have more natural syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make this function work in C++0x using automatic type deduction. However, I can't make it work without that. Native C arrays are not supported very well in C++ - their syntax is exceedingly hideous. You should use a wrapper class.

```
template<typename T, int firstdim, int seconddim> class TwoDimensionalArray {
    T data[firstdim][seconddim];
public:
    T*& operator[](int index) {
        return data[index];
    }
    const T*& operator[](int index) const {
        return data[index];
    }
};
class Myclass {
public:
    typedef TwoDimensionalArray<int, 5, 5> arraytype;
private:
    arraytype myarray;
public:
    arraytype& get_array() {
        return myarray;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Myclass m;
    Myclass::arraytype& var = m.get_array();
    int& someint = var[0][0];
}
```

This code compiles just fine. You can get pre-written wrapper class inside Boost (boost::array) that supports the whole shebang.

Comment: Doesn't compile with GCC: the first return data[index] makes a non-const reference from an rvalue, it says.

Comment: And that is the case, a bare pointer should be returned, not a reference to a pointer. Otherwise, we have at least gain much in readability. One minor point: why using `int` for the actual template types ? Something that cannot possibly be negative would be better expressed with an unsigned integer type I think.

Comment: data[index] is an lvalue, not an rvalue, much like *ptr is an lvalue. Not that the reference is really necessary, I think it's from a previous version of the code, you could probably remove it.

Comment: @Matthieu: You don't have to prevent against negative numbers here (the compiler will do that for you) and int makes a better default int type: e.g. cases where you want the difference of two sizes.