# Returning a two dimensional array in c++ without Vector

Tags: c++

Can you return in c++ a two dimensional array without using vectors or pointers?

I found this answer but I don't want to manage the ram myself when using pointsers https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172103/4954387

Comment: Use `std::array<std::array`.

Comment: The answer you've link is terrible. Arrays can't be passed by value in c++. That's one of the reasons [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) exists. The alternative would be to accept an array where the results can be written as an additional argument to your function. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use `std::vector`?

Comment: Why no vectors?

Comment: It is a condition in extra exercises from university. This is the smallest part of the execercise, but it is also the hardest part.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you return in c++ a two dimensional array without using vectors or
>   pointers?

Only if the size is known at compile time and only if you wrap the array in a class type. Just like one-dimensional arrays. You cannot return arrays directly.

```
struct Array
{
    int array[2][3];
};

Array f()
{
    return Array { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 };
}

int main()
{
    auto const array = f();
}
```

If you consider using a class like `Array`, think twice and mind that the standard library already offers `std::array` for that.

If you don't know the size at compile time, drop the "without using vectors" requirement and use `std::vector`.