# C++ function not returning 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I am writing a Qt application for matrix arithmetic . I taken input of 2 3x3 arrays in `x1 and y1` if `int` is selected and in `x2 and y2` if `float` is selected . Have a look at MainWindow.cpp .

MainWindow.cpp

```
int x1[3][3],y1[3][3];
float x2[3][3],y2[3][3];
matrix<int> m1 ;
matrix<float> m2 ;
void MainWindow::addcheck(){
    typecheck();
    if(ui->intradio->isChecked()){
        int** add1 = m1.add(x1,y1);
        putresult1(add1);
    }
    else if(ui->floatradio->isChecked()){
        int** add2 = m2.add(x2,y2);
        putresult2(add2);
    }
}
```

I am passing these 2 arrays in add function of the matrix class as shown below .

matrix.h

```
template <class T>
class matrix
{
public:
    matrix();
    T** subtract(T**&,T**&);
    T** add(T**&,T**&);
    T** multiply(T**&,T**&);
};
```

matrix.cpp

```
template <class T>
T** matrix<T>::add(T**& a, T**& b) {
    T c[3][3] ;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j] ;
        }
    }
    return c ;
}
```

However, Im recieving the following error while returning the 2d array to ** . Im unable to decrypt the error .
Error:

```
/Users/sarthakmunshi/prac/mainwindow.cpp:74: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'int **' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'int [3][3]'
        add1 = m1.add(x1,y1);
                      ^~
/Users/sarthakmunshi/prac/matrix.h:10: passing argument to parameter here
    T** add(const T**&,const T**&);
                      ^
```

Comment: why a reference to a pointer-to-pointer `T**&`?

Comment: please don't do this. Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Comment: Is that 3 levels of indirection

Comment: i have to use primitive arrays for some reason !

Comment: Double pointer for passing  a 2d array !?!

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector>>` is not appropriate to matrices. You don't have the guarantee that all the lines have the same size ! The best way to manage mathematical matrices is to use only one vector of `n x m` values and manage accesses to point the good address (as in blas/lapack)

Comment: Is there a simpler way, I can pass and recieve a 2d array ?

Comment: You are returning a variable 'c' from your 'add' method. You mustn't do it, 'c' is created on stack and when it goes out of scope you can't rely on it.

Comment: show how `x1` and `y1` are declared and initialized. then if that compile error is gone, you will get undefined behaviour from returning the local variable `c` in `matrix::add`

Comment: Any decent matrix implementation would store the rows sequentially in a one dimensional array of size m*n. Unless the size is static, in which case there is no need for indirection.

Comment: @Rames but I'm returning it to ** .??

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617683/return-a-2d-array-from-a-function) question can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of what you may have heard before, arrays are not pointers. A bidimensional array has little to do with a pointer to a pointer, which is your compile issue: there is no way of getting from a 2D array to a pointer-to-pointer.

If your arrays are fixed size, you can change the signature of the functions to require it (and incidentally *build*, which is good, right?):

```
?? add(T (&a)[3][3], T (&b)[3][3]);
```

but you are left with what to return from there... of course the answer is `Matrix<T>`, right? Adding two matrices returns a matrix, which would indicate that the function you are looking for is more like (as a free function):

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T> add(Matrix<T> const & lhs, Matrix<T> const & rhs);
```

Which, of course can be spelled:

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T> operator+(Matrix<T> const & lhs, Matrix<T> const & rhs);
```

I would recommend that you create a minimal matrix class (google, you can see many reference implementations) or that you use one from an existing library.

Comment: Isn't there a rudimentary way of simply passing a 2d array to a method, calculating and then returning it back to another 2d array ?

Comment: @saru95: You can pass an array by reference (or pointer), but the problem would be what to return. Either you return a pointer/reference to one of the arguments (you could have `add` mean `+=` and modify the first argument in place) or you need to create an array... arrays cannot be passed or returned by value in the language, which means that you would need to dynamically allocate and return a pointer complicating lifetime for the users... arrays are not really first class citizens in C or C++

Comment: Oh ! are you suggesting i cange `c[3][3]` in my code to dynamically allocated version !?

Comment: @saru95: No, I am suggesting **not** to do that. I am suggesting that you make `Matrix` a real matrix (holds data) and work in terms of *Matrix* objects rather than plain arrays. Yes, by dynamically allocating the arrays you can manage to get something that builds and works... and is quite hard to use correctly and easy to use incorrectly; don't go there.