# C++ 2D Array - Error invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create MxN matrix using 2D-arrays in C++.

The createMatrix() function asks for user input for matrix items and the printMatrix() function has to print the matrix.

But the printing task is not working (I can't access the array created, I don't understand why)

I receive the error :

```
matrix.cpp:35:20: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
    cout << matrix[i][j];
```

The code I'm working with is:

```cpp
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

// user input matrix
int createMatrix(int m, int n){
    int arr[m][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << "A[" << i << "][" << j << "] : ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return arr[m][n];
}

/*
void printMatrix(int matrix[][2], int m, int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
*/

int main(){ 
    int m = 2, n = 2; // m = rows, n = columns
    int matrix = createMatrix(m,n);

    //  printMatrix(matrix, m, n); // not working as sub-routine too, main target to make it work with sub-routine

    // to print matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function signature is not correct to return a two-dimensional array. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617683/return-a-2d-array-from-a-function for more information.

Comment: you return int not int** in your function. also I could not understand how 'int arr[m][n];' line is compiled. you should not be able to use variables in array creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`matrix` is an `int` not an `int[][]`.  Since it is an `int` there is no subscript operator and that is why you are getting the error you are getting.  You are also using veriable length arrays which is not standard C++.  I would suggest you change your code to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> createMatrix(int m, int n)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(m, std::vector<int>(n));
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << "A[" << i << "][" << j << "] : ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

And then `main()` would be:

```
int main(){ 
    int m = 2, n = 2; // m = rows, n = columns
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix = createMatrix(m,n);

    //  printMatrix(matrix, m, n); // not working as sub-routine too, main target to make it work with sub-routine

    // to print matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now i gotta understand how vector works here. thanks for answer

Comment: Why vector? it is always should be so difficult? Can't it be pointer?

Comment: @Michail Sure you could use pointers.  IDK why you would when using C++ gives you nice shiny things like vector that handle allocation and memory for you.  BTW what is difficult about a vector?

Comment: To not became stupid. :) It is C++. You need to think about memory to make good programs on it.

Comment: @Michail What?  using a vector might add a couple integers vs an array but the vector manages the memory for you, is just as fast and IMHO much easier to pass around and manipulate than a naked array.

Comment: vector solution seems better to me (I generally don't have to write extra long codes)

Comment: Of course it will work. But it is lazy way to work. And Sid Vishnoi: it is pointer. :)

Comment: @Michail Yes, lazy is a very good trait for a programmer. If you want complexity for the sake of it, go program in C.

Comment: @NathanOliver I used vector notation in printMatrix() like this : 

`vector < vector <int> > printMatrix(vector < vector <int> > matrix, int m, int n){
 for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
   cout << matrix[i][j];
  }
 }
}
`
http://i.imgur.com/mnieVhP.png
its giving :
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @SidVishnoi You have to allocate `m * n` elements first, via `std::vector<vector<int>> matrix(n, std::vector<int>(m));`.

Comment: @SidVishnoi you are getting a segfault as there is no return statement.  instead of `vector < vector <int> > printMatrix` just make it `void printMatrix`

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ `vector<vector<int>> matrix(n, vector<int>(m));`

Comment: thanks @NathanOliver for making me understand (a part of) vectors :)

Comment: @SidVishnoi BTW if I were writing the print function and I have a new compiler I would use this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cf1cdfd91912c0b

Comment: thanks @NathanOliver though I'll try to start from basics now

Comment: @SidVishnoi No problem with learning the basics.  I am just showing you what is possible and how the language is being used now.

Answer (score 0):

Your *matrix* is not array. it is *int*.

You need to work with the pointers.

Comment: any other way? because it works fine when i use them without sub-routines (create and print) (I'm new to C++)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `createMatrix` works but you won't be able to do anything with what it created. Because:

1. `arr[n][m]` is local (and out of boundaries by the way). It is not a matrix as you probably thought but an item of arr at position [n][m].
2. It is not well defined to declare array of fixed sizes with vary sizes that depend on function input.

You need to pass to `createMatrix` array from the `main()` as pointer (like you did in `printMatrix`) and `createMatrix` should work with it and not something local.

Now regarding your original question:

> But the printing task is not working (I can't access the array
>   created, I don't understand why)

`matrix` was defined as `int`, not as array.

> int matrix = createMatrix(m,n);

Comment: can i use it like 
int matrix[m][n] =  createMatrix(m,n); ?

Comment: @Sid Vishnoi Two things. One is - define your matrix in the main as `int matrix[2][2]` (unless `m` and `n` are macros), using variable to declare marixs size is not by the standard. Two is - No, your current `createMatrix` returns an item (not an array and not a matrix but a integer of `arr` at position `[n][m]`). Declare `void createMatrix(int matrix[][2], int rows_num)` and implement it accordingly.