# use a returned array on the fly, how to release its memory?

Tags: c++, function, memory, multidimensional-array

I just learned how to correctly return an array, [Return a 2d array from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617683/return-a-2d-array-from-a-function), but how can I release the memory of a returned array used on the fly if I want to do something like the following

```
dMAT=matmul(DIM,transpose(DIM,EState),dMAT);
```

where both Matmul and Transpose are user-defined functions returning a 2D array. Since now Matmul and Transpose are used on the fly, I don't have a handler towards the returned arrays and thus cannot release the memory in the said method.

EDIT:

An example of Matmul and Transpose are given below,

```
 double **transpose(int & dim, double ** mat){

   double **mat1 = new double *[dim];
   for(int i=0; i<dim; i++) {
     mat1[i] = new double [dim];
     for(int j=0; j<dim; j++) mat1[i][j] = mat[j][i];
   }

   return mat1;

 }


 double **matmul(int & dim, double ** mat1, double **mat2){

   double **mat3 = new double *[dim];
   for(int i=0; i<dim; i++) {
     mat3[i] = new double [dim];
     for(int j=0; j<dim; j++) {
        mat3[i][j]=0.0;
        for(int k=0; k<dim; k++) mat3[i][j]+=mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
     }
   }

   return mat3;

 }
```

Comment: In C++, you generally don't (use standard containers or smart pointers).

Comment: What type of array ? C style array ? Dynamically allocated array ? ? ``std::vector`` or ``std::array`` ? You should add the prototype of your functions.

Comment: Have you learned the difference between memory allocation via `malloc` (as one might get when working with C APIs from C++) and via `new`?

Comment: Unlearn it. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @n.m.  I am not used to template, but try to use the most familiar way to finish work first.

Comment: @user2079303, thanks for pointing it out, typo corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::vector`; it will save you a lot of trouble.

In your code, there is no way to release memory without having a temporary variable on which you can call delete. `std::vector` (and other [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) wrappers) will help you by managing the lifetime of the resources (here the memory).

Using C-style coding (manual memory management with `new` and `delete`) is not the way to write code in C++: it's hard and you will write buggy code. Learn good C++ coding style ([RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), ...) from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

you can make something like that:

```
double *f(const int& size) 
{
   double *arr = new double[size];
   for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
       arr[i] = i;

   return arr;
}

int main()
{
  double *a = f(10);
  delete []a;
}
```

it is not for 2d array but I think you understand main idea

Comment: I need something to be on the fly.

Comment: you can use it on fly.
try to use stl container, like vector or array

Answer (score 1):

You use a class, which encapsulates the allocation and freeing.

Something like

```
class matrix {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> mat;
public:
    matrix(int dim) : mat(dim, std::vector(std::vector(dim))) {}
    // Other members, e.g. transpose, operator+ and operator*
};
```

Or, rather than writing it yourself, you use a library like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) that has written it for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I just learned how to correctly return an array

Since it is not possible to return an array by value, it will be useful to be precise: You've learned how to return a pointer that holds the address of an object that is an element of an array.

> how can I release the memory of a returned array

You allocated the memory by calling `new[]`. Therefore you must release the memory by calling `delete[]`. `delete[]` is used by passing the address returned by `new[]` as an argument.

Since you wish to use the pointer not only for releasing the memory, but also to pass it to another function `matmul` (or sometimes `matmul`?), you will want to store the pointer in a variable so that you can copy it:

```
auto arr = transpose(DIM,EState);
dMAT = matmul(DIM,arr,dMAT);
// now, you can release the memory pointed by arr
```

---

However, don't shoot yourself in the foot by storing dynamic memory in bare pointers. Use RAII containers such as `std::vector` instead.