# Facing error in c++ arrays and pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am writing this c++ code to multiply two 2d matrices and return the resultant 2d matrix.

> The error is cannot convert ll (*)[2]  to ll**

```
ll** multiply(ll a[2][2],ll b[2][2])
{
    ll ans[2][2];
    ans[0][0]=((a[0][0]*b[0][0])%mod+(a[0][1]*b[1][0])%mod)%mod;
    ans[0][1]=((a[0][0]*b[0][1])%mod+(a[0][1]*b[1][1])%mod)%mod;
    ans[1][0]=((a[1][0]*b[0][0])%mod+(a[1][1]*b[1][0])%mod)%mod;
    ans[1][1]=((a[1][0]*b[0][1])%mod+(a[1][1]*b[1][1])%mod)%mod;
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are Not Pointers

Comment: ll stands for long long

Comment: Just use `std::array` instead of messing around with pointers and raw arrays?

Comment: Even if this compiled it would be wrong because you are trying to return the address of a local variable.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617683/return-a-2d-array-from-a-function

Answer (score 2):

You have a fallen into a trap that seems to get a lot of newcomers to the language.

Passing 2D arrays to a function and returning 2D arrays to a function leads to error prone code. Using a `strut`/`class` removes those errors.

In your case, since the size of the arrays is fixed, you can easily use a `struct`

```
struct MyMatrix
{
   ll data[2][2];
};
```

then, update `multiply` to use `MyMatrix` instead of 2D arrays.

```
MyMatrix multiply(MyMatrix const& a, MyMatrix const& b)
{
    MyMatrix ans;
    ...
    return ans;
}
```

You can change the function to an overloaded operator too.

```
MyMatrix operator*(MyMatrix const& a, MyMatrix const& b)
{
    MyMatrix ans;
    ...
    return ans;
}
```

and simplify usage to:

```
MyMatrix a{ fill in the data for a};
MyMatrix b{ fill in the data for b};
MyMatrix c = a*b;
```