# Returning a 2-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

This sounds easy and I've seen questions about this being answered by using a vector instead but I can't do that in my case so asking for help...

What should be my function signature for return2dArray() if I want to do this? Please note that I cannot use a vector. It really has to be int[][].
Thanks!

```
int* return2dArray()
{
    static int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {4, 5}};
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    auto x = return2dArray();

    for (int y = 0; y < 3 ; y++)
    {
        std::cout << "y is = " << x[y] <<std::endl;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a 2d array from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617683/return-a-2d-array-from-a-function)

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to treat the returned pointer as though it points to a simple, 1D, array, I suggest using just that -- a 1D array.

```
// int* return2dArray()
int* return1dArray()
{
    static int a[4] = {1, 2, 4, 5};
    return a;
}
```

An improvement on that would be to use a `std::array`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

std::array<int, 4>& return1DArray()
{
   static std::array<int, 4> a = {1, 2, 4, 5};
   return a;
}

int main()
{
    auto x = return1dArray();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size() ; i++)
    {
       std::cout << "x[" << i << "] is = " << x[i] << std::endl;    
    }

    // Iterate using the range-for loop.
    for ( auto e : x )
    {
       std::cout << "e is = " << e << std::endl;    
    }
}
```

`std::array` is preferable to built-in arrays since you get the `size()` member function at no additional run time penalty. You may also use `begin()` and `end()` functions if you want to iterate over the objects of the array.

Comment: Technically your example is returning a 1D array. A 2D standard array would look more like `std::array<std::array<int,4>,4>`.

Comment: @TekuConcept `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>` in that case

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is `int (f)()[2][2]`

[cdecl](https://www.cdecl.org/?q=int%20%28f%29%28%29%5B2%5D%5B2%5D)

 or simply `int f()[2][2]`

If you want to omit one or both dimensions, you should return pointer with dimensions or better `spanpack` or `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a pointer to the beginning of the 2d array since the elements are all next to each other in memory.

```
int* return2dArray()
{
    static int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {4, 5}};
    return &a[0][0];
}

int main()
{
    auto x = return2dArray();

    for (int y = 0; y < 4 ; y++)
    {
        cout << "y is = " << x[y] << endl;    
    }    
}
```

Tried it out [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/Sy-cD4kxr)

Comment: Yeah, you can do that, but it's kinda gross. have you tried `auto return2dArray() { static int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}; return a; }`? It's nice, simple, and doesn't dump all of the type information.

Comment: As much as I want to use lambdas, I have to preserve how this legacy code is written (example above is just a representation). Thanks!!

Comment: But, **pedantically**, you have UB when deferencing x[2] or use x[3], as `a` is not an array of 4 `int` (even if layout is compatible).