# How to return 2d array C++

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a function that needs to return a 2d array, I'm new in c++ but I searched a lot and the best I got is that, which gives "error: cannot convert 'int** (*)[3]' to 'int**' in return".

```
int** initial_state()
{
    int arr[3][3] =
        {
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0}}
        ;

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: try using int return type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a 2d array from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617683/return-a-2d-array-from-a-function)

Comment: Check out this thread, it asks the same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617683/return-a-2d-array-from-a-function

Comment: You can't return an array, no matter the number of "dimensions"

Comment: I must create a loop?

Comment: How would I return a pointer?

Comment: Consider using `std::array`. It supports value semantics and can be returned

Comment: If you desperately want to return a pointer, then you must use pointers to begin with, and do manual and explicit memory handling (allocation and deallocation). Using `std::array` as suggested by @user4581301 is really much easier.

Comment: warning: address of local variable 'arr' returned,   Pointers and dynamic memory - stack vs heap [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8-ht2AKyH4 ], you trying to return an array that get created on the stack and destroyed after the functions exits.

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative is using `std::vector` and simply returning `vector<vector<int>>`. In order to use `vector`, you need to include the library `vector`. (`#include<vector>`)

The code goes as following:

```
vector<vector<int>> initial_state()
{
    vector<vector<int>> arr
    {
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0} 
    };

    return arr;
}
```

If it is obligatory to use return a 2d array, then you need to declare the array as a dynamic array.

```
int** initial_state()
{
    //Create an array of pointers with size 3.
    int** arr = new int* [3];

    //Each pointer points to an array with size 3.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[3];
    }

    //Fill the 2d array with values.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```