# Issue with c++ referencing to function with 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, matrix, set

I'm trying to  get this matrix and print it out in the another function. The problem is that is impossible. I tried to solve it with ** and * but I got only the adress not the value but I cannot get the normal values as this in matrix 5x5. Can someone explain me what I do in a wrong way?

```
size_t matrix[5][5] =
    {
        {1, 16, 20, 23, 25},
        {6, 2, 17, 21, 24},
        {10, 7, 3, 18, 22},
        {13, 11, 8, 4, 19},
        {15, 14, 12, 9, 5},
    };
    set<bool> set1 = iterateover((size_t**)matrix)
     std::set<bool> iterateover(size_t** array)
    size_t numberofrows = sizeof(**arrayy) / sizeof(arrayy[0]);
    size_t numberofkols = sizeof(*arrayy[0]) / sizeof(arrayy[0][0]);
    std::set < bool >myset;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberofrows; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < numberofkols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << arrayy[i][j] << std::endl;
    return myset;
```

Comment: A double pointer is not the same as a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `iteratreOver` a **function template** which can take a 2D array by reference, as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T,std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void iterateOver(T (&arr)[N][M])
{
    for(std::size_t i= 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            std::cout<<arr[i][j] <<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    size_t matrix[5][5] =
    {
        {1, 16, 20, 23, 25},
        {6, 2, 17, 21, 24},
        {10, 7, 3, 18, 22},
        {13, 11, 8, 4, 19},
        {15, 14, 12, 9, 5},
    };
    //call iterateOver by passing the matrix by reference
    iterateOver(matrix);
   
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/2xcMiWo9P):

```
1 16 20 23 25 
6 2 17 21 24 
10 7 3 18 22 
13 11 8 4 19 
15 14 12 9 5
```

Answer (score 0):

you get row, col number incorrectly,it should be like this:

```
   size_t numberofrows =
        sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0]);

    size_t numberofcols = sizeof(matrix[0]) / sizeof(matrix[0][0]);
```

and you want to print out to other function lets use template

```
template <typename T>
void print_matrix(T matrix, int numberofcols, int numberofrows)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberofrows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < numberofcols; j++) {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] <<" ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

tested at : https://godbolt.org/z/vshev1e17

Answer (score 0):

if u want to define it in fun and print it in another function u need to do it dynamic not static or u can define it globally and access it from any function u defined
check this [Return a 2d array from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617683/return-a-2d-array-from-a-function)

Comment: Please do not use text speak ('u' vs 'you') and use correct punctuation (full stops at the end of sentences and capital letters at the beginning). If you are unsure, run it through an online spellchecker and formatter.