# How to declare two dimensional array of objects and return it from a function

Tags: c++

Can you please point me to the correct syntax. Here is the code so far

```
enum Color {WHITE, BLACK};

struct Square
{
  Square(Color p_color): color_(p_color) {}
  Color color_;
};

//instead of Square *, is there a clear way to express intention that function returns 
//Square[][]
Square[][] initSquare(const int rows, const int cols)
{
    Square board[rows][cols]; //Why does compiler complain that Square does not 
                              //have a default constructor? I am just declaring an 
                              //array of type Square

    for(int row=0;row<rows;row++)
            for(int col=0;col<cols;col++)
            {
                    if(col%2 == 0)
                            board[row][col]= Square(WHITE);
                    else
                            board[row][col] = Square(BLACK);
            }
      return board;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Returning multidimension array from function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716595/c-returning-multidimension-array-from-function)

Comment: In C++ you can't have arrays with dynamic size, they have to have a predefined size. To declare them dynamically, use pointers and the "new" operator.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I am unclear how to declare a two dimensional array of objects, without invoking the constructor such as Square board[rows][cols]; The other link does not seem to help with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Square board[rows][cols]; //Why does compiler complain that Square does not 
                          //have a default constructor? I am just declaring an 
                          //array of type Square
```

This invokes default constructor (i.e., `Square::Square()`). You have a constructor taking an argument. Compiler does not provide the default constructor if user overloaded the constructor. So compiler is complaining about it.

Secondly, you can not return the `board` from the function. `board` is a block scoped variable and it's life time ends as soon as the function returns. You should go for dynamic allocation instead.

Edit:
Avoid dynamic allocations, if possible. Using `std::vector` can simplify the task much better. Google about STL container `std::vector` if you are not aware of it.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

enum Color {WHITE, BLACK};

struct Square
{
  Color color_;
};

typedef vector<vector<Square> > chessBoard;

chessBoard initSquare(int rows, int cols)
{
    chessBoard board;

    for (int i=0; i<rows; ++i)
    {
        vector<Square> vSqr(cols); // You can pass the argument to the constructor
                                   // giving the second parameter here. But I
                                   // changed your interface a bit.

        for (int j=0; j<cols; ++j)
        {
            vSqr[j].color_ = (j%2 == 0) ? WHITE : BLACK;
        }
        board.push_back(vSqr);
    }

    return board;
}

int main()
{
    chessBoard board = initSquare(8,8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do i declare a two dimensional array of Square objects, which actually calling constructor?