# Error when using public member function to access private member variable: Variable "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, class, oop, static, private

**Update for anyone having trouble returning multidimensional arrays**

Further reading: [Returning multidimensional array from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716595/c-returning-multidimension-array-from-function)

I've declared a `static int` variable in my header. I've defined it in the `.cpp` file (Implementation file?), as shown with the relevant code below...

## Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

class Card {
private:
    static int  _palette[][3];
public:
    static int  palette();
};

#endif /* CARD_H */
```

## Card.cpp

```
int Card::_palette[][3]=    {
    {168, 0,   32},
    {228, 92,  16},
    {248, 216, 120},
    {88,  216, 84},
    {0,   120, 248},
    {104, 68,  252},
    {216, 0,   204},
    {248, 120, 248}
};

static int palette(){
    return _palette;
}
```

But when I compile, I get this error:

```
..\source\src\Card.cpp: In function 'int palette()':
..\source\src\Card.cpp:42:9: error: '_palette' was not declared in this scope
  return _palette;
```

Shouldn't my accessor function `palette()` be able to get the value of private member `_palette`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `Card::`

```
int (*Card::palette())[3]{
    return _palette;
}
```

You shouldn't have `static` in the method definition. Also, you're trying to return an `int[][]` when you should return an `int`.

Change your class to this:

```
class Card {
private:
    static int  _palette[][3];
public:
    static int  (*palette())[3];
};
```

Comment: I now have this error: `error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]`. Changing function type to `static int*` gives this error: `error: cannot declare member function 'static int* Card::palette()' to have static linkage [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @Username You probably want to remove the `static` keyword from the method definition. Keep it in your class definition, but only if you actually need it.

Comment: @IsaacH Even after changing class declaration of the public member function to `int**`, along with it's definition, I still get the `invalid conversion` error. I want to access the array so I can loop thru it. That means I want to return the array, no?

Comment: @Username see code above.Don't forget to update the type in your class too.

Comment: Your latest edit gives me no errors. Thought I don't understand what's happening. I'm new to C++. Can you help me  understand what your code does?

Comment: @Username Because you are returning `_palette`, you have to make the function type match that. `_palette` has the type `int[][3]`, so `(*palette())[3]` is compatible with that. `static` isn't allowed in the method definition, nothing to understand there, just the rule (same goes for `virtual`). And adding the `Card::` was required so we know it's a method and not just some random free function.

Comment: Sorry I suggested `**int` the first time. That would work in C, which I'm more used to, but not C++.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the method name is `Card::palette`, not just `palette`. And `Card::palette` is what you should use in the method definition.

Secondly, static method definition is not supposed to include the keyword `static`.

Thirdly, how are you expecting to be able to return an array as an `int` value??? Given the declaration of your `_palette` array, to return it from a function you'd have to use either `int (*)[3]` return type or `int (&)[][3]` return type

```
int (*Card::palette())[3] {
    return _palette;
}
```

or

```
int (&Card::palette())[][3] {
    return _palette;
}
```

And a typedef can make it more readable.