# How to return a Multidimensional Array? Error C2440

Tags: c++

I've opened a .csv file and saved its contents to a 2-dimensional array. When I try to return its value I get the error mentioned.

Everything works if I don't use the function or if I don't return the array. What is the best way to do this?

```
 string read_csv()
 {
     std::ifstream file_csv("C:\\DRT\\Lista de Materiais\\Lista.csv");
     string csv_temp[600][40]

     while (std::getline(file_csv, temp)) 
     {
         j = 1;
         while (temp != "")
         {
             pos = temp.find(",");
             csv_temp[i][j] = temp.substr(0, pos);
             temp = temp.substr(pos + 1, string::npos);
             j = j + 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return csv_lista;
}

int main()
{
    string csv[600][30];
    csv = read_csv();
}
```

C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::string [300][30]' to 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return array in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function)

Comment: First, your return type is only `string` not a multi-dimensional array of strings. Second, you cannot return c-style arrays in C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning multidimensional array from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716595/returning-multidimensional-array-from-function)

Comment: You also never declared ´´´csv_lista´´´ or assigned any values to it, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use std::array instead of c-style array to avoid usual beginner problems. You can't pass a c-style array to a function or return a c-style array from a function. The array decays to a pointer and the pointer is passed. This problem is solved with std::array:

In C++ array indexes start with 0.

```
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

using CSV = std::array<std::array<string, 30>, 600>;

CSV read_csv();

int main() {
    auto csv = read_csv();
}

CSV read_csv() {
    std::ifstream file_csv("Lista.csv");
    CSV csv_temp;

    std::string temp;
    for (std::size_t i{0}; i < csv_temp.size() && std::getline(file_csv, temp); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j {0}; j < csv_temp[i].size() && temp != ""; ++j) {
            auto pos = temp.find(",");
            csv_temp[i][j] = temp.substr(0, pos);
            temp = temp.substr(pos + 1, string::npos);
        }
    }
    return csv_temp;
}
```

Comment: Note that `auto` doesn't work like that until C++14 or later. For C++11 and earlier, you will need to actually declare the return type as an array.

Comment: @Chipster We are in 2019. If someone uses C++11 or older instead of C++14 or C++17 he should mention it in the question and tag the question correspondingly.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Hey, thanks, that fixed it. But now I wanted to do something else. Let's say I want the auto read_csv() to be in other file. If I do that, I get the "Identifier not found" error.

How should I forward declare this function? Forward declaring it as "auto read_csv();" gives me the error:

"'read_csv': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined"

Comment: @LuísF. You can't use auto in this case if you want to split declaration and definition. I fixed my answer

Comment: @ThomasSablik It works thanks. but, I had to change:

_using CSV = std::array<std::array<string, 600>, 30>;_

**to**

_using CSV = std::array<std::array<string, 30>, 600>;_

Comment: @LuísF. Ok, I changed it in my answer.